How to handle database commit errors in FastAPI
I'm putting together an api to record weather readings from a Raspberry Pico. What I need help with is error handling. The code shown here technically is trapping the error and sending back a response that there was an error, but it is really not doing it correctly.
First, I need to have it send back the actual error. I would have thought it would be easy to pull that out of e but I'm not able to.
Next, this sends back a 200 OK code and that is not good. I need to send back the proper code when something fails on the server side. I don't know what that proper code should be nor do I know how to send that back so I could use some help here as well.
Finally, is doing a rollback all I need to do here? Should I be closing the session? That being said, should I be closing the session in general if things go well?
@app.post("/reading")
async def record_reading(sensor_id: int, fahrenheit: float, pressure: float, humidity: float, dew_point: float, battery: float):
    weather_reading = WeatherReading(
                    sensor_id = sensor_id,
                    fahrenheit = fahrenheit,
                    pressure = pressure,
                    humidity = humidity,
                    dew_point = dew_point,
                    battery = battery
                    )
    try:
        session.add(weather_reading)
        session.commit()
        return {"reading added"}
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        session.rollback()
        return {"Error during commit"}


You generally shouldn't send internal database error messages to end users. It can potentially reveal private data.

You should log the error message somewhere that the programmers and DBA can get it, so they can try to resolve the root cause.

That makes good sense and I didn't think of that. What about the error code? How do I return an error code rather then the 200?

See https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/

I'd also like to note that {"Error during commit"} creates a set in Python, which can't be serialized to JSON.

Ia'm still getting my hands around all this. The guide I'm following returned the response this way so I was following along.
https://mattermost.com/blog/building-a-crud-fastapi-app-with-sqlalchemy/

So you are looking for something like this?
from fastapi import HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError

@app.post("/reading")
async def record_reading(sensor_id: int, fahrenheit: float, pressure: float, humidity: float, dew_point: float, battery: float):
    weather_reading = WeatherReading(
        sensor_id=sensor_id,
        fahrenheit=fahrenheit,
        pressure=pressure,
        humidity=humidity,
        dew_point=dew_point,
        battery=battery
    )
    try:
        session.add(weather_reading)
        session.commit()
        return {"message": "Reading successfully"}
    except SQLAlchemyError:
        session.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Something went wrong on server.Please try again later.")
    finally:
        session.close()


P.S. don't forget to always close your session. I've made this at finally block

Yes, thank you!
